# Tracking rotation amount, then either subtracting or adding to a scale based on anti clockwise or clockwise revolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'd like to track how much a wheel has been spun and apply this to a scale from -1 to 1.

For example. He/she has spun the wheel 2 times clockwise. The scale will increase by 0.5. He/she spins the wheel 3 times anti clockwise, it will decrease by 0.75.

So far I have the wheel spinning (I'm using a touch device)

```
void Update () 
{
    changeTurnAmount (); 
    int nbTouches = Input.touchCount;
    if(nbTouches > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbTouches; i++)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
            TouchPhase phase = touch.phase;
            switch(phase)
            {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                //TODO
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Moved:
                // Here the wheel is moved
                wheel.transform.Rotate (0, 0, -(touch.deltaPosition.x), Space.World);
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Stationary:
                //TODO
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Ended:
                //TODO
                break;
            case TouchPhase.Canceled:
                //TODO
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to work out here how I can get store the angleChange (ideally positively or negatively, so it may be 520 and then go down to 300 if it was being rotated left).

```
public GameObject wheel;
public float rotationRate;
public float turnAmount;
public float angleChange;
private float previousAngle;
private float currentAngle;
private float newAngle;

void Start() {
    currentAngle = wheel.transform.rotation.z;
}

private void changeTurnAmount()
{
    previousAngle = currentAngle;
    currentAngle = wheel.transform.rotation.z;

    angleChange = previousAngle - currentAngle;

    turnAmount += angleChange;

    print (turnAmount);
}
```

However, turn amount normally equals something like 0.4. An example console log was '0.495072'

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or code snippets!

Comment: what if you use decimal instead of float?

Comment: Thanks for looking bpursley but that didn't make a difference sadly. Out of curiousity what was your thinking behind this?

Comment: Sometimes floats can lose precision and I thought maybe 0.5 was becoming 0.495072 after some operations were done.  Just a shot in the dark

Comment: `transform.rotation` returns a quaternion and those are not in degrees. Use `transform.rotation.eulerAngles` for working with degrees.